# How to construct a block-walking argument proof for $\sum_{k=0}^l {l-k \choose m} {q+k \choose n} = {l+q+1 \choose m+n+1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

While reading Concrete Math by Knuth and attempting to construct a block-walking argument proof for the equation (5.26) in Table.169, it seems the target of the path is off by one block and stops at ${l+q\choose m+n}$ instead of ${l+q+1\choose m+n+1}$, can anyone shed some light on the possible mistake that caused the difference?

Comment: Could you post the work you've done toward a proof?

Comment: It seems that if we consider $\binom{l-k}{m}$ as the number of ways to walk from block (0,0) to block $(l-k,m)$, then  $\binom{q+k}{n}$ can be seen as the number of ways to walk from block $(l-k,m)$ to block $(l+q,n+m)$, where $k\leq l$ and $n\geq q$.

Answer (score 1):

> The number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m+1+n,l-m+q-n)$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{(m+1+n)+(l-m+q-n)}{m+1+n}=\binom{l+q+1}{m+n+1}
> \end{align*}
>   since the length of each path is $(m+1+n)+(l-m+q-n)=l+q+1$ and we have to select $m+1+n$ $(1,0)$-steps in $x$-direction, leaving $l-m+q-n$ $(0,1)$-steps in $y$-direction.
>
> Now we fix a vertical line going through $(m,0)$. Each path from $(0,0)$ to $(m+1+n,l-m+q-n)$ will cross the line at some point $(m,l-m-k)$ with $0\leq k\leq l-m$.

We can so *partition* all valid paths by taking paths crossing the line at a specific height $l-m-k$.

[image]

The number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m+1+n,l-m+q-n)$ passing $(m,l-m-k)$ is the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,l-m-k)$ times the number of paths from $(m,l-m-k)$ to $(m+1+n,l-m+q-n)$.

Note that from $(m,l-m-k)$ we do horizontal step $(1,0)$ to $(m+1,l-m-k)$, since the vertical step from $(m,l-m-k)$ to $(m,l-m-k+1)$ is already contained  when considering all paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,l-m-k+1)$.

> - The number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,l-m-k)$ is $$\binom{l-k}{m}$$
> - The number of paths from $(m,l-m-k)$ to $(m+1,l-m-k)$ is $1$
> - The number of paths from $(m+1,l-m-k)$ to $(m+1+n,l-m+q-n)$ is
>     $$\binom{((m+1+n)-(m+1))+((l-m+q-n)-(l-m-k))}{(m+1+n)-(m+1)}=\binom{q+k}{n}$$
> - The number of  paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m+1+n,l-m+q-n)$ passing $(m,l-m-k)$ and $(m+1,l-m-k)$ is $$\binom{l-k}{m}\binom{q+k}{n}$$
>
> Since $k$ may vary from $0$ to $l-m$ we finally get the Chu-Vandermonde Identity in the form
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{l-m}\binom{l-k}{m}\binom{q+k}{n}=\binom{l+q+1}{m+n+1}}
> \end{align*}